# How to run grep with multiple AND patterns?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I would like to get the multi pattern match with implicit **AND** between patterns, i.e. equivalent to running several greps in a sequence:

```
grep pattern1 | grep pattern2 | ...
```

So how to convert it to something like?

```
grep pattern1 & pattern2 & pattern3
```

*I would like to use single grep because I am building arguments dynamically, so everything has to fit in one string. Using filter is system feature, not grep, so it is not an argument for it.*

---

Don't confuse this question with:

```
grep "pattern1\|pattern2\|..."
```

This is an **OR** multi pattern match. I am looking for an **AND** pattern match.

Comment: Similar: [Match all patterns from file at once](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332160/21471)

Comment: Similar question on SO: [Check if multiple strings or regexes exist in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49762772/6862601)

Comment: If you're looking for the grep syntax for "find lines that contain `foo` and lines that contain `bar`" see [using grep for multiple search patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610642/using-grep-for-multiple-search-patterns)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

To find the lines that match each and everyone of a list of patterns, `agrep` (the original one, now shipped with [glimpse](https://github.com/az143/glimpse), not the unrelated one in the [TRE regexp library](https://laurikari.net/tre/download/)) can do it with this syntax:

```
agrep 'pattern1;pattern2'
```

With GNU `grep`, when built with PCRE support, you can do:

```
grep -P '^(?=.*pattern1)(?=.*pattern2)'
```

With [ast `grep`](https://github.com/att/ast/blob/master/src/cmd/re/grep.c):

```
grep -X '.*pattern1.*&.*pattern2.*'
```

(adding `.*`s as `<x>&<y>` matches strings that match both `<x>` and `<y>` *exactly*, `a&b` would never match as there's no such string that can *be* both `a` and `b` at the same time).

If the patterns don't overlap, you may also be able to do:

```
grep -e 'pattern1.*pattern2' -e 'pattern2.*pattern1'
```

The best portable way is probably with `awk` as already mentioned:

```
awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/'
```

Or with `sed`:

```
sed -e '/pattern1/!d' -e '/pattern2/!d'
```

Or `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if /pattern1/ && /pattern2/'
```

Please beware that all those will have different regular expression syntaxes.

The `awk`/`sed`/`perl` ones don't reflect whether any line matched the patterns in their exit status. To so that you need:

```
awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/ {print; found = 1}
     END {exit !found}'
```

```
perl -ne 'if (/pattern1/ && /pattern2/) {print; $found = 1}
          END {exit !$found}'
```

Or pipe the command to `grep '^'`.

For potentially gzip-compressed files, you can use `zgrep` which is generally a shell script wrapper around `grep`, and use one of the `grep` solutions above (not the ast-open one as that `grep` implementation cannot be use by `zgrep`) or you could use the `PerlIO::gzip` module of `perl` which can transparently uncompress files upon input:

```
perl -MPerlIO::gzip -Mopen='IN,gzip(autopop)' -ne '
  print "$ARGV:$_" if /pattern1/ && /pattern2/' -- *.gz
```

(which if the files are small enough at least is even going to be more efficient than `zgrep` as the decompression is done internally without having to run `gunzip` for each file).

Comment: The `agrep` syntax is not working for me... which version was it introduced in?

Comment: @Raman [2.04 from 1992](ftp://ftp.cs.arizona.edu/agrep/) already had it. I've no reason to believe it wasn't there from the start.  Newer (after 1992) versions of `agrep` can be found included with [glimpse/webglimpse](http://webglimpse.net/trial/glimpse-latest.tar.gz). Possibly you have a different implementation. I had a mistake for the ast-grep version though, the option for _augmented regexps_ is `-X`, not `-A`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, I have `agrep` 0.8.0 on Fedora 23. This appears to be a different `agrep` than the one you reference.

Comment: @Raman, yours sounds like [TRE `agrep`](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Indeed it is. Too bad Fedora doesn't have the `agrep` you are referring to, out of the box.

Comment: `awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/'` is good, but how do i calculate count for this?

Comment: @Techiee, you mean the count of lines that match either pattern or the count of occurrences of each pattern? In any case, it seems it would be a different question.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Right now `awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/'` is printing all the lines, i want the print the count of such lines. Can you help? Thanks

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I got it, `awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/' filename | wc -l` will give me desired output.

Comment: @Techiee, or just `awk '/p1/ && /p2/ {n++}; END {print 0+n}'`

Comment: The `awk` solution doesn't work for me on Cygwin. Looks like it is but checking the process shows that it's doing nothing, no CPU usage at all.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I am getting `grep: invalid matcher .*pattern1.*&.*pattern2.*`

Comment: @ChamindaBandara, you ran that with GNU `grep` instead of ast `grep`. GNU `grep` has no support for ast augmented regexp. It does have an undocumented `-X` option, but that's for something unrelated, it's to specify the regexp flavour (*matcher*) like in `grep -X perl` being the same as `grep -P`.

Comment: Honestly, I've tried at least half of these suggestions in the example and none of them work as described.

Comment: @DanielKaplan, from your recent question, I suspect you're looking for something difference from what this Q&A is about. Here we're trying to find *lines* that match all patterns, while you may be trying to find *files* for which all patterns are matched by any line (there are several Q&As here covering that). I've edited the answer to maybe make that more obvious.

Comment: Ah! OK, I see. My mistake.

Comment: Note that `awk` exits with a 0 status code even when no matches are found. You can fix this by piping to `grep .`

Comment: @BallpointBen, see edit.

Answer (score 30):

You didn't specify grep version, this is important. Some regexp engines allow multiple matching groupped by AND using '&' but this is non-standard and non-portable feature. But, at least GNU grep doesn't support this.

OTOH you can simply replace grep with sed, awk, perl, etc. (listed in order of weight increasing). With awk, the command would look like

```
awk '/regexp1/ && /regexp2/ && /regexp3/ { print; }'
```

and it can be constructed to be specified in command line in easy way.

Comment: Just remember that `awk` uses ERE's, e.g. the equivalent of `grep -E`, as opposed to the BRE's that plain `grep` uses.

Comment: `awk`'s regexes are *called* EREs, but in fact they're a bit idiosyncratic. Here are probably more details than anyone cares for: http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Regex

Comment: Thank you, grep 2.7.3 (openSUSE). I upvoted you, but I will keep question open for a while, maybe there is some trick for grep (not that I dislike `awk` -- simply knowing more is better).

Comment: The default action is to print the matching line so the `{ print; }` part isn't really necessary or useful here.

Comment: This still returns a `0` status code if the match fails.

Comment: @BallpointBen If you mean return code from `awk`, well, it requires explicit generation because awk program doesn't "know" what is positive result for the programmer. You may add a variable used as boolean and to select exit code in END block.

Comment: @Netch Actually I think the easiest way is just pipe `awk` to `grep .`.

Answer (score 19):

#### [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)

Here is the syntax using [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) combining multiple patterns using *Boolean* expressions:

```
git grep --no-index -e pattern1 --and -e pattern2 --and -e pattern3
```

<sup>The above command will print lines matching all the patterns at once.</sup>

> `--no-index` Search files in the current directory that is not managed by Git.

Check `man git-grep` for help.

See also:

- [How to use grep to match string1 AND string2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4487328/55075)
- [Check if all of multiple strings or regexes exist in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49762772/55075).

For *OR* operation, see:

- [How do I grep for multiple patterns with pattern having a pipe character?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37313/21471)
- [Grep: how to add an "OR" condition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25821/44425)

Comment: Superb answer. Thank you.

Comment: This worked the best for me

Comment: This will only match a file if a line is found that matches all patterns, not files where the patterns match individual lines. Use `--all-match` and `--or` instead of `--and` for that.

Answer (score 17):

> `grep pattern1 | grep pattern2 | ...`
>
> I would like to use single grep because I am building arguments *dynamically*, so everything has to fit in one string

It's actually possible to build the pipeline dynamically (without resorting to `eval`):

```bsh
# Executes: grep "$1" | grep "$2" | grep "$3" | ...
function chained-grep {
    local pattern="$1"
    if [[ -z "$pattern" ]]; then
        cat
        return
    fi    

    shift
    grep -- "$pattern" | chained-grep "$@"
}

cat something | chained-grep all patterns must match order but matter dont
```

It's probably not a very efficient solution though.

Comment: Use either `chained-grep()` or `function chained-grep` but not `function chained-grep()`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73750/difference-between-function-foo-and-foo

Comment: Can you describe what the trick is? Can you add it to the answer (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar ) by [editing it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/326270/edit)?

Comment: Reformulated the answer to make the trick clearer (ie.: build a shell pipeline dynamically)

Comment: The important part here is that shell allows recursion which makes this possible. Note the keyword `local` in front of variable that must be unique for the recursion. Also note that keyword `local` is not POSIX so using shebang `#!/bin/sh` may not be safe, see details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493743/20336

Answer (score 12):

If `patterns` contains one pattern per line, you can do something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)if($0!~i)next}1' patterns -
```

Or this matches substrings instead of regular expressions:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)if(!index($0,i))next}1' patterns -
```

To print all instead of no lines of the input in the case that `patterns` is empty, replace `NR==FNR` with `FILENAME==ARGV[1]`, or with `ARGIND==1` in `gawk`.

These functions print the lines of STDIN which contain each string specified as an argument as a substring. `ga` stands for grep all and `gai` ignores case.

```
ga(){ awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)if(!index($0,i))next}1' <(printf %s\\n "$@") -; }
gai(){ awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]{a[tolower($0)];next}{for(i in a)if(!index(tolower($0),i))next}1' <(printf %s\\n "$@") -; }
```

Comment: crisp answer which addresss several uses cases and works (verified on macos)

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take, and this works for words in multiple lines:

Use `find . -type f` followed by as many  
`-exec grep -q 'first_word' {} \;`  
and the last keyword with  
`-exec grep -l 'nth_word' {} \;`

`-q` quiet / silent  
`-l` show files with matches

The following returns list of filenames with words 'rabbit' and 'hole' in them: 
 `find . -type f -exec grep -q 'rabbit' {} \; -exec grep -l 'hole' {} \;`

Comment: If you look carefully, you just might learn that this is not the functionality that the question is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

to search multiple files for the presence of two patterns anywhere in the file use

```
awk -v RS="" '/patern1/&&/patern2/{print FILENAME}' file1 ... filen
```

Comment: Grep is all too often used where (IMO) awk would be better.   I like this answer for exactly that reason, and of course awk can do further processing such as printing only fields 6 and 2 from the input.

Comment: This doesn't actually address the OP's question, but +1 'cause I think it's very useful for other related situations & reveals the strength of `awk`... if you had to choose `awk` or `grep`, I think it's clear. Fortunately we don't have to make this choice :)

Answer (score 1):

#### [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

Here is the example using [`rg`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep):

```
rg -N '(?P<p1>.*pattern1.*)(?P<p2>.*pattern2.*)(?P<p3>.*pattern3.*)' file.txt
```

It's one of the quickest grepping tools, since it's built on top of [Rust's regex engine](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/regex) which uses finite automata, SIMD and aggressive literal optimizations to make searching very fast.

<sup>See also related feature request at [GH-875](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/875).</sup>

Answer (score -2):

To find *all* of the words (or patterns), you can run `grep` in a `for` loop. The main advantage here is searching from a **list of regular expressions**.

A real example:

```
# File 'search_all_regex_and_error_if_missing.sh'

find_list="\
^a+$ \
^b+$ \
^h+$ \
^d+$ \
"

for item in $find_list; do
   if grep -E "$item" file_to_search_within.txt
   then
       echo "$item found in file."
   else
       echo "Error: $item not found in file. Exiting!"
       exit 1
   fi
done
```

Now let's run it on this file:

```
hhhhhhhhhh
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbb
ababbabaabbaaa
ccccccc
dsfsdf
bbbb
cccdd
aa
caa
```

```
$ ./search_all_regex_and_error_if_missing.sh
aaaaaaa aa
^a+$ found in file.
bbbbbbbbb bbbb
^b+$ found in file.
hhhhhhhhhh
^h+$ found in file.
Error: ^d+$ not found in file. Exiting!
```

Comment: Your logic is faulty -- I asked for `ALL` operator, your code works as `OR` operator, not `AND`. And btw. for that (`OR`) is much easier solution given right in the question.

Comment: @greenoldman The logic is simple: The for will **loop on ALL of the words/patterns** in the list, and if it is found in file - will print it. So just remove the else if you don't need action in case word was not found.

Comment: I understand your logic as well as my question -- I was asking about `AND` operator, meaning the file is only a positive hit if it matches pattern A and pattern B and pattern C and... `AND` In you case file is positive hit if it matches pattern A or pattern B or... Do you see the difference now?

Comment: @greenoldman not sure why you think this loop does not check AND condition for all patterns? So I've edited my answer with a real example: It will search in file for all regex of list, and on the first one which is missing - will exit with error.

Comment: You have it right in front of your eyes, you have positive match just after first match is executed. You should have "collect" all outcomes and compute `AND` on them. Then you should rewrite the script to run on multiple files -- then maybe you realize that the question is already answered and your attempt does not bring anything to the table, sorry.

Comment: @greenoldman sorry I don't get your point. `^a+$` , `^b+$` , `^h+$` are all positive match, but `^d+$` is not a match, so the search then breaks. That's exactly the meaning of **AND condition**! You don't have to print anything during the loop, just after it ends, if that's what you want.

Comment: Of course, I could add variable tracking whether `AND` condition is fulfilled, and then I would have an **extra** script instead of short and concise call of grep which was posted and accepted as solution **six** years ago. Take signal to noise into consideration and please delete your entire answer -- it does not add anything really.

Comment: @greenholdman, why do you think it doesn't add anything? It's a great solution to verify numerous words/regexs. Imagine grep -e 'pattern1.*pattern2' -e 'pattern2.*pattern1' on 10+ regex, not just two...

Comment: Note that this answer is about searching for all patterns and reporting if each pattern cannot be find at least once in the file. The original question was about matching ALL the patterns against ALL the lines instead of matching files.

Comment: The accepted answer starts with the phrase, _"To find the lines that match each and everyone of a list of patterns... "_. So presumably that's what the OP desires. Does perchance this solution return ___filewise___ matches instead of ___linewise___ matches? If so, it seems this answer could be tweaked to return the latter.