# How to call a shell function

Tags: shell-script, function

How can I use the integer value returned by a function in shell script that takes some arguments as input?

I am using the following code:

```
fun()
{
    echo "hello ${1}"
    return 1
}

a= fun 2
echo $a
```

I am not sure how should I call this function. I tried the methods below, bot none of them seems to work:

```
a= fun 2
a=`fun 2`
a=${fun 2}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exit code is contained in `$?`:

```
fun 2
a=$?
```

Answer (score 1):

you may have a look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742783/returning-value-from-called-function-in-shell-script with a long and well explained answer. Regards.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

function producer_func()
{
    echo "1"
    echo "[ $1 ]"
    echo "2"
    echo "3"
}

function returner_func()
{
    echo "output from returner_func"
    return 1
}

#just print to stdout from function
producer_func "aa ww"
echo "--------------------"

#accumulate function output into variable
some_var=$(producer_func "bbb ccc")
echo -e "<$some_var>"
echo "--------------------"

#get returned value from function, may be integer only
returner_func
echo "returner_func returned  $?"
echo "--------------------"

#accumulate output and get return value
some_other_var=`returner_func`
echo "<$some_other_var>"
echo "returner_func returned  $?"
echo "--------------------"
```

[nice bash tutorial, link points to functions invocation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html)

Comment: FYI, this uses a [nonstandard function definition syntax](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74045/135943).