# Version Update from 14.04.3 LTS to 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

I have recently Updated from 14.04.3 LTS to 16.04.2 LTS. My shell scipts that got executed on 14 version are failing in the latest version i.e. 16.04.2.
Below are the sample errors:

```
test: 24: test: function: not found
test: 25: [: Illegal number: !
test.sh: 33: test.sh: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

The lines have the following information in the script

```
24 line : function CheckErrors {
25 line :  if [ ! $1 -eq 0 ]; 
    then
    echo "****************************************"
    echo "STEP FAILED: $2                         "
    echo "Terminating execution and exiting       "
    echo "****************************************"
    exit 1
  fi
33 line : }
```

Are there any changes between both the versions?

Comment: Do you have `#!/bin/bash` in the first line of the script?

Comment: If the script is not too long, it will be useful if you'll [edit] your question and add the full script

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Yes i have the code in the start

Comment: #!/bin/bash 
. ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

Starting off, I would change your scripts syntax to this:

```
CheckErrors(){
if [ $1 -dt 0 ]; 
    then
    echo "****************************************"
    echo "STEP FAILED: $2                         "
    echo "Terminating execution and exiting       "
    echo "****************************************"
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

This should make your script less error prone during an update cause:

- [`function`](https://ss64.com/bash/function.html) keyword is optional(and is a "bashism"). Use `func(){commandA; commandB }` instead. This will [make your scripts more portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73750/difference-between-function-foo-and-foo) if a shell change(`/bin/sh`) occurrs during upgrades;
- You dont need to valuate *if result is not equal zero* (`if [ ! $1 -eq 0 ]`). Evaluate if result is different then(`-dt`) zero (`if [ $1 -dt 0 ]`).

My suspect here is that you were using `bash` shell before the upgrade as the default `/bin/sh`, since `dash` needs the `()` at the end of the function name while for `bash` is enough to have `()`, `function` keyword or both. Take a look at [this example](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) of `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
function quit {
    exit
}
function hello {
    echo Hello!
}
hello
quit
echo foo
```

The error line `test: 24: test: function: not found` makes me question if you are really using `bash` at all, so...

**My answer:** put the shebang on your scripts pointing to `#!/bin/bash` and use `./test.sh` to run it or follow [this Ask Ubuntu solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834853/ubuntu-bash-functions-syntax-error-or-unexpected).

Comment: Hi I have replaced with the code you sent and below is the response

Comment: pentaho:~/repository$ sh test.sh
test.sh: 9: test.sh: CheckErrors: not found
test.sh: 10: test.sh: if[: not found
test.sh: 11: test.sh: Syntax error: "then" unexpected

Comment: You have to run the script with `./test.sh`  and not `sh test.sh` after editing shebang on first line.... Have you read my answer at all?