# shell script error : Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, syntax

I have checked the previous post on this error. still did not get the solution working. Here is my bash script. can some one help me figure out the issue . I have used https://www.shellcheck.net/ to see any error. I did not find any.

**Error:**

```
Dockerfunctiontest.sh: 2: Dockerfunctiontest.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

**script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
function BuildSimpleContainer ()
{
docker search mariadb
docker pull mariadb:latest
docker run --name mariadbtestfour -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass -d mariadb --log-bin --binlog-format=MIXED
docker exec -it mariadbtest bash
apt-get -qq update
apt-get -qq -y install curl
apt-get -qq -y install wget
apt-get update
apt-get install apt-transport-https
apt-get update
cd /home
mkdir mdsd
cd mdsd/
wget '<blob url to pfx file>'
echo "certififcate Downloaded"
wget '<blob url file1>'
echo "file1 Downloaded"
wget 'blob url file2'
echo "file2 Downloaded"
}   
BuildSimpleContainer
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory: the `(` shouldn't be there on line 2.

Comment: How do you call this script?

Comment: @tomasz has hit it right on the nose.  The script is being executed by `sh`, not `bash`, and is choking on the function declaration syntax.

Comment: Related: [difference between "function foo() {}" and "foo() {}"](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/74045)

Answer (score 10):

My guess is that you don't run this script as a Bash script, but with some other shell, which doesn't accept this syntax. Eg. `sh`.

As you can see in Shellcheck, and as Bash's `man` on my Debian confirms, this syntax is correct:

```
name () compound-command [redirection]
function name [()] compound-command [redirection]
```

You are using the second one from the two above, and your `compound-command` is the contents of the `{...}` braces. And that's fine as far as `man bash` goes. But then, there are voices against this construct, as in [the link in John Moon's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74045/157965) below the other answer. And in [the link to Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#function_foo.28.29) in that answer again.

Going back to your question, taking into consideration the name of the script, namely `Dockerfunctiontest.sh`, I might think you don't see much difference between `sh` and `bash`. Probably you run the script with this command:

```
sh Dockerfunctiontest.sh
```

While it would be reasonable to run it with either:

```
bash Dockerfunctiontest.sh
```

or

```
./Dockerfunctiontest.sh
```

The last one picks the interpreter basing on the first line in the script, namely:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

And while the interpreter named in the script is Bash, why not name the file the proper way?

```
Dockerfunctiontest.bash
```

Less confusion in the future.

Answer (score -2):

It's simple! Just remove the  `(` and `)` from the declaration and try again, as [difference between "function foo() {}" and "foo() {}"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73750/difference-between-function-foo-and-foo/74045#74045) says.

Comment: Why are you recommending the least portable version? The POSIX variant without the word `function` would seem to be the canonical variant

Comment: How do you know they're running that with a Korn-compatible shell then? Also, the error message is exactly what Dash would give, and it only supports the POSIX-style function definition. `function foo` would be valid syntax in Dash, but it'd try to run a command called `function`. (Dash is `/bin/sh` in Debian and Ubuntu.)