# Linux shell script: Run a program only if it exists, ignore it if it does not exist

Tags: shell, scripting, executable

I am programming a **Linux shell script** that will print status banners during its execution only if the proper tool, say `figlet`, is **installed** (this is: reachable on system **path**).

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "foo"
figlet "Starting"
echo "moo"
figlet "Working"
echo "foo moo"
figlet "Finished"
```

I would like for my script to work **without errors** even when `figlet` is **not installed**.

What could be a **practical method**?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

Comment: @sudodus : just ignoring the 'figlet' (and its parameters) command would be OK. Continuing execution, of course.

Comment: The title to this question got me in all sorts of metaphysical problems

Comment: Do you want to ignore **all** errors? Just use `figlet ... || true`.

Comment: If you don’t care about exit codes a shortcut is to use `figlet || true`, but in your case probably a shell function which Echos plaintext If no Banner can be printed is more likely what you want.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

My interpretation would use a wrapper function named the same as the tool; in that function, execute the real tool if it exists:

```
figlet() {
  if command -p figlet  >/dev/null 2>&1
    then 
      command figlet "$@"
    else
      :
    fi
}
```

Then you can have `figlet arg1 arg2...` unchanged in your script.

@Olorin came up with a simpler method: define a wrapper function only if we need to (if the tool doesn't exist):

```
if ! command -v figlet > /dev/null; then figlet() { :; }; fi
```

If you'd like the arguments to `figlet` to be printed even if figlet isn't installed, adjust Olorin's suggestion as follows:

```
if ! command -v figlet > /dev/null; then figlet() { printf '%s\n' "$*"; }; fi
```

Comment: Where does `command` come from? I don't have it in my installations (Red Hat 6.8 Enterprise and Cygwin64).

Comment: @eewanco, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250/117549; long story short, it's built in to bash, which is probably your shell.

Comment: `command` is a POSIX Bourne shell builtin. It normally executes the command provided, but the `-v` flag makes it behave more like `type`, another shell builtin.

Comment: @eewanco `type -a command` will show you. `which` will *only* show executables on your `$PATH`, not built-ins, keywords, functions or aliases.

Comment: @l0b0: on RedHat-family with bash and the default profile(s) `which` _does_ find an applicable alias, because it aliases `which` itself to run `/usr/bin/which` and pipe it a list of the shell's aliases to look in (!) (Of course `\which` suppresses the alias and uses only the program, which doesn't show aliases.)

Comment: Apparently, `command` only ignores shell builtins when executing. Hence, the "wrapper" does *not* work as intended.

Comment: @JeffRSon I'm confused; a shell builtin would certainly execute before a function; a missing shell builtin would be an indication of a much different problem. Can you elaborate on the failure case you're encountering?

Comment: I'm sorry ;-) for me, after defining the wrapper, calling figlet (the function) always tries to execute non-exisiting figlet (a binary). AFAICT, `command -v` recognizes the function as existing command, hence trying to call the binary via command (which ignores the function preventing endless loops...) leading to "figlet not found".

Comment: Interesting; thanks, @JeffRSon! I wonder how I (and many others, including the OP) missed that case! I'll edit the question to use `command -p` instead, so that we're simply looking up the path in the test instead of executing it.

Answer (score 17):

You can test to see if `figlet` exists

```
if type figlet >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo Figlet is installed
fi
```

Answer (score 8):

At the start of your script, check if `figlet` exists, and if it does not, define a shell function that does nothing:

```
type figlet >/dev/null 2>&1 || figlet() { :; }
```

`type` checks if `figlet` exists as a shell built-in, function, alias, or keyword, `>/dev/null 2>&1` discards stdin and stdout so you don't get any output, and if it does not exist, `figlet() { :; }` defines `figlet` as a function that does nothing.

This way you don't have to edit every line of your script that uses `figlet`, or check if it exists every time `figlet` is called.

You can add a diagnostic message, if you like:

```
type figlet >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo 'figlet not installed.' ; figlet() { :; } ; }
```

As a bonus, since you didn't mention which shell you are using, I believe this is POSIX compliant, so it should work on most any shell.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer. You could also replace `type figlet >/dev/null 2>&1` with `hash figlet 2>/dev/null` if you're using bash. (The OP said "if it's in my PATH".)

Answer (score 7):

A common way to do this is with `test -x` aka `[ -x`. Here is an example taken from `/etc/init.d/ntp` on a Linux system:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/lockfile-create ]; then
    lockfile-create $LOCKFILE
    lockfile-touch $LOCKFILE &
    LOCKTOUCHPID="$!"
fi
```

This variant relies on knowing the full path of the executable. In `/bin/lesspipe` I found an example which works around that by combining `-x` and the `which` command:

```
if [ -x "`which bunzip`" ]; then bunzip -c "$1"
else echo "No bunzip available"; fi ;;
```

That way this will work without knowing in advance where in the `PATH` the `bunzip` executable is.

Comment: [Don't use `which`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then). And even if `which` worked, using `test -x` on its output is silly: if you get a path from `which`, it exists.

Comment: @Gilles: Technically speaking, `test -x` does more than just check if a file exists (that's what `test -e` is for). It also checks if the file has the execute permissions set.

Comment: @comfreak So does `which`.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative -- a pattern I've seen in project auto configure scripts:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/figlet ]
then
    FIGLET=/usr/bin/figlet
else
    FIGLET=:
fi

$FIGLET "Hello, world!"
```

In your specific case you could even do,

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/figlet ]
then
   SAY=/usr/bin/figlet
elif [ -x /usr/local/bin/figlet ]
then
   SAY=/usr/local/bin/figlet
elif [ -x /usr/bin/banner ]
then
   SAY=/usr/bin/banner
else
   SAY=/usr/bin/echo
fi

$SAY "Hello, world!"
```

If you don't know the specific path, you can try multiple `elif` (see above) to try known locations, or just use the `PATH` to always resolve the command:

```
if command -v figlet >/dev/null
then
    SAY=figlet
elif command -v banner >/dev/null
then
    SAY=banner
else
    SAY=echo
fi
```

In general, when writing scripts, I prefer to only call commands in specific locations specified by me.  I don't like the uncertainty/risk of what the end user might have put into their `PATH`, perhaps in their own `~/bin`.

If, for example, I was writing a complicated script for others that might remove files based on the output of a particular command I'm calling, I wouldn't want to accidentally pick up something in their `~/bin` that might or might not be the command I expected.

Comment: What if `figlet` was in `/usr/local/bin` or `/home/bob/stuff/programs/executable/figlet`?

Answer (score 3):

```
type -p figlet > /dev/null && figlet "foo"
```

The bash `type` command finds a command, function, alias, keyword, or builtin (see `help type`) and prints out the location or definition. It also returns a return code representing the result of the search; true (0) if found. So what we're doing here is trying to find `figlet` in the path (`-p` means only look for files, not built-ins or functions, and also suppresses error messages), discarding output (that's what `> /dev/null` does), and if it returns true (`&&`), it will execute `figlet`.

This is simpler if `figlet` is in a fixed location:

```
[ -x /usr/bin/figlet ] && /usr/bin/figlet "foo"
```

Here we're using the `test` command (a.k.a. `[`) to see if `/usr/bin/figlet` is executable (`-x`) and if so (`&&`) execute it. This solution I think is more portable than using `type` which is a bashism I believe.

You could make a function that does this for you:

```
function x() {
    if type -p "$1" >/dev/null; then
        cmd="$1"
        shift
        "$cmd" "$@"
    fi
}
```

(The quotes are necessary owing to potential spaces)

Then you'd just do:

```
x figlet "foo"
```

Comment: `type` [is POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html) but `type -p` is a `bash` extension. You could simplify your function, replacing `cmd=$1; shift; "$cmd" "$@"` with just `"$@"`. Don't use the `function` keyword either, as that's also [not POSIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73854/100397). The result then becomes `x() { type "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 && "$@"; }` with a hope that for `bash`, `$1` doesn't start with a dash (`-`)

Answer (score 1):

o/,
I would say something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# if figlet is installed :
if [ "$(which figlet 2>/dev/null)" ]; then
       # do what you wanted to do
       echo "foo"
       figlet "Starting"
       echo "moo"
       figlet "Working"
       echo "foo moo"
       figlet "Finished"
# if not
else
       # exit program with an error
       echo "please install figlet"
       exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a test execution, suppressing any output, and test success/failure code. Choose arguments to figlet to make this test inexpensive. -? or --help or --version are obvious possibilities.

```
if figlet --help >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    # figlet is available
    echo "foo"
    figlet "starting"
    #etc
else
    rc=$?
    echo "figlet is not installed or not working correctly (return code ${rc})"
fi
```

Added in response to comment below: if you really want to test that figlet exists, not that it's usable, then you would do

```
figlet --help >/dev/null 2>&1 
rc=$?
if [ $rc -eq 127 ] ; then # 127 is "command not found" on linux bash 4.4.23(1)
    echo "command figlet not found"
else
    figlet "whatever" # use figlet
fi
```

Comment: The problem here is that figlet can fail for reasons besides not being installed, so just testing the exit code doesn't suffice.

Comment: If you really want to test only for its installation, then you want to test if `$?` equals 127 (on my linux system). 127 is "command not found". But my thinking is that for rational commands, if `command --help` fails, then the installation is borked sufficiently that it might as well not be there!.

Comment: 126 is "command found but not executable," so you would want to test against that as well. Unfortunately, you can't depend on `--help` being available. Posix utilities don't have it, for one, and posix guidelines actually [recommend against it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02). `at --help` fails with `at: invalid option -- '-'`, for instance, and an exit status of `130` on my system.

Comment: Also, of course, if figlet can exit with status 127 that could be a problem too.

Comment: Fair point about 126. **Most** **sane** utilities have some sort of lightweight harmless command options, such as `-?` `--help` `--version` ... or you could find out what `figlet -0 --illegal` exits with, and treat that as your success indicator (as long as it's not 127, which I would class as sabotage).