# grep. Find multiple AND patterns in any order using single condition

Tags: grep

Is there any way to use `grep` to search for entry matching multiple patterns in any order using single condidion?

As showed in [How to run grep with multiple AND patterns?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55359/how-to-run-grep-with-multiple-and-patterns) for multiple patterns i can use

```
grep -e 'foo.*bar' -e 'bar.*foo'
```

but i have to write 2 conditions here, 6 conditions for 3 patterns and so on...
I want to write single condition if possible.
For finding patterns in any order you can suggest to use:

```
grep -e 'foo' | grep -e 'bar' # at least i do not retype patterns here
```

and this will work but i would like to see colored output and in this case only **bar** will be highlighted.

I would like to write condition as easy as

```
awk '/foo/ && /bar/'
```

if it is possible for `grep` (awk does not highlight results and i doubt it can be done easily).

`agrep` can probably do what i want, but i wonder if my default grep (2.10-1) on ubuntu 12.04 can do this.

Comment: Your doubts are probably ill-founded.

Comment: @Derp - see the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15945400). Though `awk '/foo/ && /bar/' | grep -E 'foo|bar'` would also do what you want...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your version of `grep` supports PCRE (GNU `grep` does this with the `-P` or `--perl-regexp` option), you can use lookaheads to match multiple words in any order:

```
grep -P '(?=.*?word1)(?=.*?word2)(?=.*?word3)^.*$'
```

This won't highlight the words, though. Lookaheads are zero-length assertions, they're not part of the matching sequence.

I think your piping solution should work for that. By default, `grep` only colors the output when it's going to a terminal, so only the last command in the pipeline does highlighting, but you can override this with `--color=always`.

```
grep --color=always foo | grep --color=always bar
```

Comment: I was only able to get the whole line highlighted using GREP_COLORS. Is request to have only the matching words highlighted?

Comment: No, this will not highlight the words. Lookaheads are zero-length assertions, so they don't actually form part of the match. So the option to highlight the match will highlight the part of the line that matches `^.*$`, which is the whole line.

Answer (score 4):

## New command based on old answer

```
#!/bin/bash
# Build search pipeline
n=$#
SEARCH=""
while [ $n -gt 0 ]; do
    if [ -n "$SEARCH" ]; then
            SEARCH="|${SEARCH}"
    fi
    SEARCH="grep --color=always '${!n}'${SEARCH}"
    n=$[ $n - 1 ]
done
# Execute all greps in sequence
/bin/bash -c "${SEARCH}"
```

So, as requested:

> I would like to write condition as easy as `awk '/foo/ && /bar/'`

```
yagrep SEARCH grep color < /usr/local/bin/yagrep
```

**SEARCH**="**grep** --**color**=always '${!n}'${**SEARCH**}"

## Old answer

A complex option would be to generate all permutations of the patterns, supply them to `grep` and hope that the regexp compiler generates a reasonably optimized search tree.

But even with a small number of patterns, say six, the permutations would be 6!, or 720. It makes for an awkward command line.

But seeing as you seem to have no quarrels with piped `grep` except

> and this will work but I would like to see colored output

then, **provided that**:

- the patterns do not overlap
- the patterns do not contain term control characters

an acceptable solution would be to pipe several `grep`s, each with one pattern, in order of increasing likelihood so as to minimize the load.

Then to ensure that the colorization works, you'll have to force `grep` into [believing that its standard output is a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe) using `faketerm` or otherwise, or if available (it should be), you can use the `--color=always` option:

```
cat file | grep --color=always pattern1 \
         | grep --color=always pattern2 \
         ...
         | grep --color=always patternN
```

(A nice twist would be to wrap the `grep`s into a single string to be executed by a subshell, and generate the string programmatically using e.g. `sed`).

Comment: Note that you don't need the `--color` option on the last line

Answer (score 0):

You can colorise output with `sed`

```
sed -n "/foo/{/bar/s/foo\|bar/\x1b[1;31m&\x1b[m/gp}"
```

Comment: I suspected it is possible, but i think you agree it can't be applied manually when i want to search quickly for some substring using cmd line on some random machine :)

Comment: @Derp You can arrange it like function in `bashrc` :`sed -n "$(for k in "$@";do a=${a:+${a}{}/$k/;b=$b$s;s='}';c=${c:+$c\\\|}$k;done;printf "%s" "$a" 's/' "$c" '/\x1b[1;31m&\x1b[m/gp' "$b")"`

Answer (score 0):

The following is simple to remmember although the intent is not that clear:

```
cat file | grep pattern1 | grep pattern2 | grep pattern3 | grep -e pattern1 -e pattern2 -e pattern3
```

Answer (score -4):

You could do this with a single OR-based regexp. Given the file contents:

```
This is my file
It has many words
There are also many chars
```

The following grep command would highlight the 'my' and 'There' in a single argument:

```
grep -P -e '(there|my)' testfile
```

Simply separate each regex pattern with a `|` (pipe) to indicate OR.

Comment: Yes, it will highlight both patterns. But i need AND, not OR. In your example grep will match string with any of given pattern. Also i think in this case you can replace `-P -e` with `-E`.