# How to search efficiently for a list of strings in a big code directory

Tags: grep, performance, search

I have a list of strings, for every of those strings, I want to check if it occurs in a big source code directory.

I came to a GNU grep solution that gives me what I want:

```bash
for key in $(cat /tmp/listOfKeys.txt); do
    if [ "$(grep -rio -m 1 "$key" . | wc -l)" = "0" ]; then
        echo "$key has no occurence"; 
    fi
done
```

However, it's not efficient at all since it always grep every file of the directory, even if it finds a match early. Since there are a lot of keys to lookup, and pretty much files to search in, it is not usable as-is.

Do you know a way to do this efficiently with a "standard" unix tool?

Comment: What is a "standard" unix tool? Folks have been writing new software, e.g. http://betterthanack.com/

Comment: I agree it's a bit vague. I expected something like grep, awk, ... that allows me do everything in a few command lines. I don't know Ack, it might be a good match but it seems it makes some semantic-based assertions and I'd like to avoid that. However, I'd be curious to see what proposition you could do with that tool. I'll try it anyway, thanks.

Comment: Have used [CodeSearch](https://github.com/google/codesearch) for static code bases. It takes some time (and resources) to index huge source trees, but once done searches are *very fast*. Not sure how this fits your Q though.

Comment: You may want to look at `ctags` or `cscope` to index your code if those strings are code symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can at least be simplified to:

```
set -f # needed if you're using the split+glob operator and don't want the
       # glob part

for key in $(cat /tmp/listOfKeys.txt); do
   grep -riFqe "$key" . ||
    printf '%s\n' "$key has no occurrence"
done
```

Which would stop searching after the first occurrence of the `key` and not consider the key as a regular expression (or possible option to `grep`).

To avoid having to read files several times, and assuming your list of keys is one key per line (as opposed to space/tab/newline separated in the code above), you could do with GNU tools:

```
find . -type f -size +0 -printf '%p\0' | awk '
  ARGIND == 2 {ARGV[ARGC++] = $0; next}
  ARGIND == 4 {a[tolower($0)]; n++; next}
  {
    l = tolower($0)
    for (i in a) if (index(l, i)) {
      delete a[i]
      if (!--n) exit
    }
  }
  END {
    for (i in a) print i, "has no occurrence"
  }' RS='\0' - RS='\n' /tmp/listOfKeys.txt
```

It's optimised in that it will stop looking for a `key` as soon as it's seen it and will stop as soon as all the keys have been found and will read the files only once.

It assumes keys are unique in `listOfKeys.txt`. It will output the keys in lower case.

The GNUisms above are `-printf '%p\0'`, `ARGIND` and the ability of `awk` to handle NUL delimited records. The first two can be addressed with:

```
find . -type f -size +0 -exec printf '%s\0' {} + | awk '
  step == 1 {ARGV[ARGC++] = $0; next}
  step == 2 {a[tolower($0)]; n++; next}
  {
    l = tolower($0)
    for (i in a) if (index(l, i)) {
      delete a[i]
      if (!--n) exit
    }
  }
  END {
    for (i in a) print i, "has no occurrence"
  }' step=1 RS='\0' - step=2 RS='\n' /tmp/listOfKeys.txt step=3
```

The third one could be addressed with tricks like [this one](/a/134270), but that's probably not worth the effort. See [Barefoot IO's solution](/a/267693) for a way to bypass the problem altogether.

Comment: I wasn't aware of ARGIND (perhaps because I rarely use gawk). I like what you did there; it's a clever and succinct way of not only passing pathnames robustly but of having gawk read them automatically.

Comment: @BarefootIO, glad you like it. ARGIND can easily be emulated with other awks (see edit). The true gawk-specific feature here is the ability to deal with NUL delimited records.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. It's very efficient and does the job well. Thank you!

Comment: To find all of the strings inside a file, you can run grep in FOR loop: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462445/43233

Answer (score 5):

GNU grep (as well as most variants I know of) offer a `-f` option, which does exactly what you need. The `fgrep` variant treats the input lines as plain ordinary strings instead of regex's.

```
fgrep -rio -f /tmp/listOfKeys.txt .
```

And if you just want to test if at least one match is found, add `-q` option. Per Stéphane's comment, if you need to know which strings that were *not* found, add the `-h` option and then pipe through this common awk idiom:

```
fgrep -h -rio -f /tmp/listOfKeys.txt . |
awk '{$0=tolower($0)}; !seen[$0]++' |
fgrep -v -i -x -f - /tmp/listOfKeys.txt
```

The second `fgrep` now uses the first `fgrep`'s ouput (uniqued case insensitively), inverts the sense, and shows non-matching strings from the keyfile.

Comment: Note that it won't give you the list of keys that are _not_ matched, but you could add the `-h` option (GNU specific) and pipe to `sort -u` and compare with the listOfKeys with `comm` (after having converted both to upper or lower case because of `-i`).

Comment: Also, `fgrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -F`.

Comment: @terdon Who the hell deprecates these things? I think they deserve a new label "deprecato-terrorist"

Comment: Heh, actually, `fgrep` has been deprecated for many years now. It still works (at least in GNU `grep`) but there's no guarantee it will continue to do so. Admittedly, `fgrep`, `egrep` etc, are kind of silly. They're just symlinks to `grep`. Using an option seems far more reasonable to me.

Comment: Is it deprecated from Solaris and AIX also? @terdon Seriously, where do I complain about this?

Comment: Dunno but `grep -E` and `grep -f` (which have replaced `egrep` and `fgrep` respectively) are both defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) (and were also defined by the previous POSIX release). The POSIX specs don't state that the `[fe]grep` are deprecated but do refer to them as "historical". Sounds like you'll need to complain to a lot of people...

Comment: @terdon, they were actually _introduced_ by POSIX, so would be in all revisions of POSIX.

Comment: Your variants find all matches of all keys or one match of any key, but the question is about finding one match for each key.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I originally had the awk idiom, then realized a second fgrep would do the trick. Is the awk really necessary at all? I don't think so.  And for some reason, my Mac's `grep` doesn't like `-f -` which I find very very strange ("No such file or directory").

Comment: @Gilles that's not so clear to me. Seems the OP is (1) wanting to find strings that are _not_ in the directory (2) read all files no more than once.

Comment: Mac's `grep` used to be GNU `grep`, but it's now a reimplementation. It looks like they broke backward compatibility when they (I don't know if "they" is FreeBSD or Apple, Apple's grep already diverges from FreeBSD) rewrote it, probably to get POSIX conformance as there's nothing in the POSIX spec that would allow `-f -` to treat `-` anything else but the `-` file in the current directory. Feel free to revert. The `awk` filter could increase performance if there's a very large list of matches. You'll want to keep `-x` though.

Comment: I haven't investigated why, but this solution lists some keys several times. Otherwise, it looks good but it's clearly not as efficient as @StéphaneChazelas 's solution.

Comment: @nimai This one is necessarily exhaustive. All the files are searched for all strings, regardless if some have already been found or not. It has the benefit of simplicity and being able to recall it from memory. Also not sure why keys are listed multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

A portable, POSIX-compliant translation of Stéphane Chazelas' gawk approach:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + |
awk '
    FNR==NR {keys[tolower($0)]; n++; next}
    {
        s = tolower($0)
        for (k in keys) 
            if (index(s, k)) {
                delete keys[k]
                if (!--n)
                    exit
            }
    }
    END {
        for (k in keys) print k, "has no occurrence"
    }
' /tmp/listOfKeys.txt -
```

Unless your source files are unusual, in that their names are consistently longer than their content, Stéphane's solution should be more efficient because less data is piped (which involves copying between buffers in two processes via the kernel).

Comment: Another benefit of your approach over mine is that if there's a very large list of files, `awk` doesn't wait for `find` to finish to find them all before starting to look for keys. The memory foot print would also be smaller.

Comment: One (pathological) case where our approaches are different is when there are files with extra data after the last newline (where the last line is not terminated) as with `cat`, that last line would be merged with the first line of the next file.

Comment: @StéphaneC: Nice catch. Conceivably that merger could lead to a false positive. Perhaps `awk 1 {} +` instead. Each of the 4 implementations (gawk, mawk, bwk awk, busybox) that I tested accept and heal a terminal fragment.  EDIT: As soon as I posted, I realized that awk's ARGV semantics (such as looking for variable assignments) would make filenames with an `=` unreadable.

Comment: At efficiency's expense, the case of the terminal fragment (sounds like the title of a Perry Mason episode) can be handled with an explicit newline after each `cat`: `find . -type f -exec cat {} \; -exec echo \;`

Comment: there's no problem with = if filenames start with ./ like here.