# Match all patterns from file at once

Tags: grep, patterns

I have 2 files: `args` and `text`. 
For example:

args: [contains arguments of a script]

```
life
happy
horse
```

text:

```
The horse has a happy life.
Life is fun.
Kids are happy.
```

I need a command that prints the lines from `text` that contain all the patterns from `args`. In this case: `The horse has a happy life.`

Comment: How many different `args` are there?

Comment: A line must match _all_ of the lines in the `args` file to be printed? Or _any_ of the lines? Either way, `grep` may be a useful command for you to investigate (`man grep`)

Comment: Must match _all_ the lines in order to be printed.

Comment: @don_crissti that's a good candidate but it doesn't really address the unknown number of patterns in the file `args`.

Comment: @roaima - I see it as a dupe, the unknown number of pattern is a secondary Q but not the main Q (and should prolly be a separate Q)

Comment: @roaima - not to mention that [one of the posts there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270700) actually _does answer this question_.

Comment: The [other question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55359/21471) is specific to `grep`, this isn't and it operates on the files as input, so the questions are a bit different, they could lead to different answers.

Answer (score 4):

#### `git grep`

Here is the syntax using [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) combining multiple patterns using Boolean expressions:

```
git grep -e "life" --and -e "happy" --and -e "horse"
```

<sup>The above command will print lines matching all the patterns at once.</sup>

If the files aren't under version control, add `--no-index` param.

> Search files in the current directory that is not managed by Git.

Check `man git-grep` for help.

#### `grep`

Normally `grep` with `-f` parameter will print lines with at least one pattern, e.g.

```
grep -f args.txt file.txt
```

In your case it won't work.

So to print lines which matches all patterns at the same time, you can try this command:

> `while read n text; do [ $n -eq $(wc -l < args.txt) ] && echo $text; done < <(while read patt; do grep "$patt" text.txt; done < args.txt | sort | uniq -c)`

Explanation:

1. The inner `while` loop will print all lines which matches at least one pattern in `text.txt` using pattern list from `args.txt` file.
2. Then this list is sorted (`sort`) and counted for number of occurrences (`uniq -c`).
3. The outer `while` loop will print only lines which have the same number of occurrences that number of patterns in `args.txt` (which is 3).

---

Another approach would be to remove all lines which does not match at least one pattern.

Here is the solution using Ex/Vim editor changing the file in-place:

```
while read patt; do ex +"v/$patt/d" -scwq text.txt; done < args.txt
```

<sup>Note: This will remove the unneeded lines from the file it-self.</sup>

Here is shorter version which will print the result on the screen only:

```
ex $(xargs -I% printf "+v/%/d " < args.txt) +%p -scq! text.txt
```

<sup>Change `+%p -scq!` to `-scwq` to save it in-place into the file.</sup>

---

And here is the solution by defining a shell alias:

```
alias grep-all="</dev/stdin $(xargs printf '|grep "%s"' < args.txt)"
```

Sample usage:

```
grep-all file.txt
```

---

Related:

- [How to run grep with multiple AND patterns?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55359/21471)
- [How to grep for 2 words existing on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6480687/55075)
- [Check if all of multiple strings or regexes exist in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49762772/55075)

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`.

```
~$ cat textlist.txt | awk '/life/ && /happy/ && /horse/ { print; }'
The horse has a happy life
```

textlist.txt being the list of sentences you gave.

Comment: `awk` knows how to read files, no need for `cat`, and I suspect that the OP wants to be able to read the patterns from a file at runtime

Comment: `args` contains the arguments of a script. I'm not supposed to know what `args` contains.

Comment: @mike-m1342 is `args` inside a flat file or are they actual script arguments? If they are script arguments, you can just use the positional parameters in awk ($1, $2, etc). Hopefully that helps, but perhaps I still don't fully understand your goal.

Comment: `args` is a file. But I placed there the script arguments. How to use `awk` with all arguments at once?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `agrep` to apply the *AND* operation. Unfortunately it can't apply *AND* to a list of patterns in a file, so you have to expand that into a command argument first.

```
patterns=$(sed 's/;/\\;/' <args | tr '\n' ';' | sed 's/;$//')
agrep "$patterns" text
```

The munging to generate the list of patterns joins them together with semicolons. However, we must not have a semicolon at the end of the list, so that gets removed, and also any pattern already containing a semicolon must have that character escaped so it's not treated as an *AND* operator. Use `echo "$patterns"` to see how the `args` file is converted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not the most efficient way of doing this, but it seem to work:

```
# for a in $(cat args); do regex="$regex | grep '$a'"; done
# eval cat text "$regex"
The horse has a happy life.
```

Comment: Note that this is not safe if file `args` contains any shell metacharacters.