# Nested piped grep results in a string saying "(standard input)"

Tags: grep, pipe

I'm performing a nested grep like this:

```
grep -ir "Some string" . |grep "Another string I want to find in the other grep's results"
```

This works perfectly as intended (I get the results from the first grep filtered by the second grep as well), but as soon as I add an "-l" option so I only get the list of files from the second grep, I don't get anything.

```
grep -ir "Some string" . |grep -l "Another string I want to find in the other grep's results"
```

This results in the following output:

```
(standard input)
```

I guess piping doesn't work when I just want the list of files. Any alternatives?

Comment: @don_crissti, I wouldn't say it's a duplicate as here the OP wants a recursive search and only one of the matches is case sensitive.

Comment: @Stéphane - indeed, the case sensitivity makes it different (I missed the `-i` of the initial `grep`) - I'm retracting my close vote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use "cut" to remove strings after ":" then you get file parts (assuming file paths don't contain colon or newline characters and don't match the second pattern themselves).

```
grep -ir "Some string" . |grep "Another string I want to find in the other grep's results" | cut -d ":" -f 1
```

in case of duplications use "uniq"

```
grep -ir "string1" . | grep "string2" | cut -d: -f1 | uniq
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas tnx for mentioning specifics, yes there would be more complexities afterwards, the whole job should be done in first grep

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've accepted your answer because it's simple and works with my version of grep.

Comment: My second grep has always been grep -v, and basically can't be done in the same command.

Comment: @OMA glad I could help.

Comment: @Joshua in case of inverse match -v, yes it can't be done in one grep, I guess the pattern I mentioned would solve this problem

Answer (score 17):

The `-l` option to `grep` will make the utility print only the name of the file containing the specified pattern.  The manual on my system says the following about this option:

> Only the names of files containing selected lines are written to
> standard output.  grep will only search a file until a match has
> been found, making searches potentially less expensive.
> Pathnames are listed once per file searched.  If the standard
> input is searched, the string "(standard input)" is written.

Since the second `grep` in your pipeline is reading from standard input, not from a file, it is unaware of where the data is coming from other than that it's arriving on its standard input stream.  This is why it's returning the text string `(standard input)`. This is as close as it can get to where the match was located.

To combine the two patterns in the first `grep` (which *does* know what files it's looking in), see [How to run grep with multiple AND patterns?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55359)

Comment: Thanks for the easy to understand explanation. Points for that. I was doing it wrong by using -l in a piped grep command, since now I realize that using it that way grep is just getting text, not files, as source. I accepted another answer, though, because it provided an easy to use working alternative.

Comment: @OMA No worries. I'm happy to have provided helpful input.

Answer (score 5):

<sup>(I'm assuming you intended the second `grep` to match on the content of line and not on the file names or both as your approach was doing)</sup>

POSIXly:

```
find . -type f -exec awk '
  FNR == 1 {found = 0}
  !found && tolower($0) ~ /some string/ && /other string/ {
    print FILENAME
    found = 1
    nextfile
  }' {} +
```

The business about `found` is for awk implementations that don't support `nextfile` yet (and where `nextfile` is then a no-op). If you know your `awk` implementation supports `nextfile`, you can simplify it to:

```
 find . -type f -exec awk 'tolower($0) ~ /some string/ && /other string/ {
    print FILENAME; nextfile}' {} +
```

With GNU `grep` built with PCRE support, since you want one match to be case insensitive and not the other:

```
grep -rlP '^(?=.*(?i:some string))(?=.*other string)' .
```

`(?=...)` is a perl *look-ahead* operator. `(?i:pattern)` turns on *case-insensitive match* for `pattern` only. So here we're matching on the beginning of the line (`^`) provided it's followed by any number of characters (`.*`) followed by `some string` (case insensitive) and also that it (the beginning of the line) is followed by any number of characters and `other string` (case sensitive).

If your `grep` doesn't support `-P`, you may have the `pcregrep` command instead (replace `grep -rlP` with `pcregrep -rl`), or if the patterns don't overlap, you could do:

```
grep -rl -e '[sS][oO][mM][eE] [sS][tT][rR][iI][nN][gG].*other string' \
         -e 'other string.*[sS][oO][mM][eE] [sS][tT][rR][iI][nN][gG]' .
```

Or if you don't care both matches being case insensitive:

```
grep -ril -e 'some string.*other string' \
          -e 'other string.*some string' .
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really don't need the second grep to be case insensitive since I know the exact string I want to look for, but I guess it wouldn't matter if it was case insensitive as well. My grep doesn't support the -P argument, unfortunately

Comment: @OMA, see edit with some more alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

You can place both paterns in one query (based on this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55359/how-to-run-grep-with-multiple-and-patterns)) using the following pattern:

```
grep -P '^(?=.*pattern1)(?=.*pattern2)'
```

In your case You can add the -ir -l parameters in the following form:

```
grep -irlP '^(?=.*pattern1)(?=.*pattern2)' .
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This just gives me the "usage" message (as if I just typed "grep" with no arguments)

Comment: Probably my grep doesn't support this. This is what I get: "usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]"

Comment: @OMA - I'm using  grep (GNU grep) 2.25, on Ubuntu 16.04 (it worked for me). I've noticed that in your original command you added a dot `.` as the path , what happened if you happened dot `.` after the grep command ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest solution of all provided.

```
find . -type f -exec perl -lne '
   /Some string/i and /other string/ and print($ARGV),close(*ARGV);
' {} +
```

---

```
grep -irZ "Some string" . |
perl -lsF'/\n/' -0ne '
   s/^/\n/ if $. == 1; s/$/\n/ if eof;

   $. == 1 and $prev = $F[1],next;
   push @{$h{$prev}}, $F[0];
   $prev = $F[1];

   END {
      grep($_ =~ /\Q${str2}/, @{$h{$_}}) and print for keys %h;
   }
' -- -str2="Another string"
```

Working principle:
Here the first `grep` does a `recursive`, `case-insensitive` search for "some string" in the current directory and downwards and generates null-separated(`\0`) records due to the `-Z` option given to `grep`.

Each of these records contain the the filename and the line that matched. Only hitch is that the ordering is not in step, due to grep's behavior of not putting a `\0` after the matching line. To get around this limitation, we make use of `Perl` reading null-separated records and splitting these records on `\n` to separate out the lines from the filenames.

Hence their is no limitation on the kinds of file names that can be involved, with the exception of `\0`, which anyway are forbidden.

Comment: That's different from what was asked as it searches for `another string` _anywhere_ in the files that contain `some string`, not only in the lines that contains `some string`.

Comment: Thanks S.C.  for catching that egregious error. I have amended and placed another fix which should ameliorate the situation.