# grep regex and variables

Tags: bash, regular-expression

My issue is as follows:

This is the content of variable res:

```
% echo $res
large__noninteractive($|[[:blank:]])" | grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])RAM.3000000($|[[:blank:]])" | grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])CORES.1
```

And when I do as follows it gives me results (everything after `grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])` and before `($|[[:blank:]])`" is the identical to the content of $res) :

```
cat queuedjobs | grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])large__noninteractive($|[[:blank:]])" | grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])RAM.3000000($|[[:blank:]])" | grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])CORES.1($|[[:blank:]])"
```

but when I do:

```
cat queuedjobs | grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])$res($|[[:blank:]])"
```

There are no results even though it is supposedly identical.
I would appreciate any ideas for solving this issue.

1. I'm testing it in the command line but it will enter into a script.
2. I made the res as follows:

   ```
   resource="large__noninteractive RAM.2500000 CORES.4"`
   res=`echo $resource | sed "s/${queue}//g" | awk '{$1=$1};1' | sed 's/ /($|[[:blank:]])" \| grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])/g'`
   ```

Comment: You can't use the pipe `|` in a variable like that. Also, in your case I'd suggest using an array of patterns and something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326270/70524 instead.

Comment: Is `cat queuedjobs | grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])$res($|[[:blank:]])"` a part of a Bash script or typed in the terminal?

Comment: Is the `grep` commands actually part of the value `$res`?

Comment: Bash script, and Yes, I inserted it like that: