# grep/awk for matching both strings

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I need to use an if statement that is true only if "is loaded" AND "is running" occur in a service status command output:

```
$groupservice status
service 1 is loaded
service 2 is running
```

As already mentioned I've tried to use this:

```
$service status | awk '/is loaded/ && /is running/'
```

but I dont' get any output.
The only way to run it is in this way:

```
if [[ $(service status | grep "is loaded") ]]  && [[ $(service status | grep "is running") ]]
```

but I'd prefer to use a shorter expression.
Where am I wrong?
thank you

Comment: The problem with your `awk` attempt is that `awk` processes the input line-wise, so your program would only work if `is loaded` and `is running` appeared on the same line. Also, you say "As already mentioned" - can you add a link _where_ you mentioned this?

Comment: `groupservice status|sed '/is loaded/!d;N;/is running/!d'`?

Comment: I found it here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55359/how-to-run-grep-with-multiple-and-patterns but here also is "already mentioned"

Comment: @Philippos, thank you it's running

Comment: not, none work for me

Comment: Wait, so you don't actually need AND, you don't want the patterns to be on the same line, you want two separate lines, right?

Comment: yes, the command output consists of many lines with "is running" or "is not running "or "is loaded" or "is not loaded. I need the if returns true if there are "is loaded" AND "is running".

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in `awk` by counting the matches:

```
$ service status | 
    awk '/is loaded/{l++} 
         /is running/{r++} 
        (l && r){
            print "found"; 
            exit 0
        }
        END{
          if  (!(l && r)){
            print "not found"; 
            exit 1
            }
        }'
```

The only way I can think of to do this with `grep` would be to `grep` the file twice. Something like this:

```
service status | 
    grep -qF 'is loaded' && foo.sh | 
        grep -qF 'is running' && 
            echo Found || 
                echo "not found"
```

Of course, that has a race condition in that if the output of `service` changes between the two invocations, you can get incorrect results. To get around that, you could use a tmp file:

```
service status > /tmp/file
grep -qF 'is loaded'  /tmp/file &&
    grep -qF 'is running' /tmp/file &&
        echo Found || 
            echo "not found"
```

Comment: Never use a variable named `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` (indistinguishable in some fonts) and so obfuscates your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, like in your posted sample input, there are no blank lines in your `service status` output then using any awk:

```
if service status | awk -v RS= '/is loaded/ && /is running/{f=1} END{exit !f}'; then
    echo "Eureka!"
fi
Eureka!
```

Obviously if all you need to do is print something then you don't need the shell `if` statement or to provide an exit status from awk:

```
service status | awk -v RS= '/is loaded/ && /is running/{print "Eureka!"}'
Eureka!
```

If there are blank lines and you have GNU awk then just change `RS=` to `RS='^$'`.

Comment: what does it mean {f=1} and {exit !f} ?

Comment: It's exactly what it looks like - `f=1` is setting a variable named `f` to the number `1` and then `exit !f` will exit with status 0 (the shell success exit status) if `f` was set, or status 1 (a shell failure exit status) otherwise. So the script will exit with success if `is loaded` and `is running` are both present, failure otherwise, exactly like grep does when it finds the regexp you're looking for. Add a `print f;` before the `exit` and/or a `echo "$?"` after the call to awk to see what it's set to for files that do/don't contain both strings if you like.