# How to run zgrep with multiple AND patterns?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, zgrep

I know how to do it with `grep`, but the command doesn't work with **zgrep**

```
grep -E 'Pattern1.*Patter2' fileName
```

I'm using **zgrep** to match patterns inside a `.json.gz` file.
Because the files are too big, I want to zgrep `BOTH` pattern1 **AND** pattern2, the order doesn't matter.

Possible to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand this question - it should work with `zgrep` aswell. My `zgrep (gzip) 1.9` says: "OPTIONs are the same as for 'grep' [...]", aside from some that don't matter for your usecase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run grep with multiple AND patterns?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55359/how-to-run-grep-with-multiple-and-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

`grep` has no logical AND operator. It is still possible to achieve the same result using a regex OR operator:

```
zgrep -E 'pattern1.*pattern2|pattern2.*pattern1' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess (but it's really not clear) that you want to find lines where both pattern1 and pattern2 are present, but in any order.

The straight-forward solution is `zcat FileName | grep -E pattern1 | grep -E pattern2`, but that means the whole decompressed file will be transferred across the first pipe.

If `zgrep` does handle this, and there is only a limited number of occurrences of `pattern1` in the file `zgrep -E pattern1 | grep -E pattern2` will work. (If `pattern2` is the rarest, you might want to switch them.)

The solution @mashuptwice gives in an answer will work, but depending on the difficulties involved in `pattern1` and `pattern2` that might be hard to enter.

And not addressing the question: I've wanted to search for two strings in any order (but not being restrained by memory), and have found that `perl -ale 'print if (/pattern1/ && /pattern2/)'` (most languages allow something similar, but I like perl) is a good solution. (In your case you'd have to handle decompression in the script)